# How to hyperlink a html/css box section?

Tags: html, css

What I want is, a css box which is hyperlinked, so that if anyone clicks on that box s/he will go to that specified link!

For example, I want to hyperlink the following  box wrapped around "My Title":

```
<header>
       <h1 class="title" style = "text-align:center; margin = 20px"> My Title </h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Did you try anything, maybe you should provide some (pseudo)code?

Comment: Do you want to create and [anchor](http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm)? i.e. `#` in HTML

Comment: @hunter I think defiant refers to the basic component in HTML's box model. It's called a box and can be denoted as <div>any content</div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
<div onclick="location.href='http://myurl.com';" >(Whatever you want in here*</div>
```

...as long as you don't mind a little JS...

Answer (score 6):

```
<div><a href="yoururl.html" style="display:block;height:100%;width:100%"></a></div>
```

basically: make a link in your box, make it a block and make it as big as the box

Comment: This worked for me.  Actually, the height: 100% and width: 100% attributes were not necessary.  The essential attribute on the anchor tag is the display: block.

Comment: I agree, thanks, but I always add it because in some cases `block` might not be 100% height and other css could overwrite the width.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a big block link like:

```
/* html */
<a id="foo" href="www.google.com"></a>

/* css */
#foo {
    background: green;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are meaning a div or a,here is the code:

```
<a href="www.google.com" style="width:100px;height:100px; float:left"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with a "css box", but I think you mean a box for clicking.
You can transform an a-tag as block element and give them a height and width.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<a href="#">"Linkbox"</a>

/* CSS */
a { 
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can either use `<a>`-Tag which is formatted via CSS into a box or surround an element with a `<a>` to make it clicky.

Comment: The last part of your answer makes invalid html in most cases.

Comment: Right, but he did not specify anything, so it was an option.

Comment: Well the <box> <inline> theory in css normally refers to 'boxes' as elements that are blocks by default like divs. blocks normally encapsulate links, not the other way around. But indeed, he couldve meant a span he set to block himself :D